# How to anchor one empty game object inside stretchable image in unity

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I'm setting up a new app UI (Android), there I need to anchor one empty game object inside a stretchable image. I tried all anchor presets, but when mobile screen resolution is changing my stretchable background image stretching according to the screen size. So I can't able to pin that game object on the specific place in the background image.[image: Here is the reference image 1] [image: Here is the reference image 2] . That Blue image is a movable image I have to stop that image at that red dot(game object).(1080p resolution)above images.

[image]
In Above image, you can see that red image went out of its actual position after changing the screen resolution.(Xperia One resolution (1644 * 3840)).

Because of this, I can't able to stop that movable blue screen at a specific position.

Note: Above all images are sorted by layer by layer with some transparent in the middle of the main image. This is for producing water filling effect in 2D.

Comment: Hard to tell what you are trying to achieve without providing any screenshots of how your desired result should look like.

Comment: @derHugo Kindly check the screen shots which i added now. Thank you for replying fast.

Comment: Could you explain more your gameplay here . It's still not understandable though you have an image there

Comment: @Ginxxx Please check now i edited my question. If you still have any doubt please replay me i'll explain you until you understand my problem. Thank you.

Comment: In the resolution where it is in correct position; Try selecting your red dot and press T and adjust your anchor points around your red dot manually (custom anchoring). That could help you out.

Comment: @SyedMunimRaza That's not a solution, it need to be automatically positioned to all screen sizes by anchoring in one screen resolution.